# how to access 'api' instance in namespace class

Tags: python, flask-restplus

I'm following the guide **:** https://flask-restplus.readthedocs.io/en/stable/scaling.html

I define namespace in each namespace class and the 'api' is defined in **init**.py.

In **init**.py

```
from flask_restplus import Api
from .AA import nsAA
api = Api()
api.add_namespace(nsAA)
```

In AA.py (which is namespace)

```
from flask_restplus import Resource, Namespace, marshal_with, fields
nsAA = Namespace('')
@nsAA.route('/login')
class AA(Resource):
    login_fields = api.model('Resource', {
    'username': fields.String,
    'password': fields.String,
})
    @api.expect(login_fields)
    def post(self):
```

I got **error:**

```
AttributeError: 'AA' object has no attribute 'api'
```

I understand that this error as there is no 'api' instance in namespace.

But how can I pass it to namespace?

Answer (score 0):

You should treat your namespaces as Flask's blueprint. For instance, you could do:

```
from flask_restplus import Resource, Namespace, marshal_with, fields

 login_fields = api.model('Resource', {
    'username': fields.String,
    'password': fields.String,
})

nsAA = Namespace('')

@nsAA.route('/login')
@nsAA.expect(login_fields)
class AA(Resource):
    def post(self):
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use namespace , the api.model and and api.expect , you need to replace with namespace.model and namespace.expect.

e.g

> login_fields = **nsAA**.model('Resource',

> @**nsAA**.expect(login_fields)